# Using Workflow in DynamicsCRM 2016 to update all contacts in Marketing List

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

We use Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016 on premise. We want to implement a workflow which updates a field of all contacts in the MarketingList. Did anyone achieve this ... How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Workflows are not designed to perform an action on collections of records. A workflow is always triggered in the context of a single entity record.

However, you can develop a custom `CodeActivity`. Create a workflow that is bound to the Marketing List entity. In the `CodeActivity` query all Contact records related to the Marketing List and update these records.

> Important: by default your workflow must complete within 2 minutes. For large data this may not be sufficient. If this is the case the preferred way to go here is creating a batch (console) program.